# Pass in a vector OnBeforeCompile Three js

Tags: three.js, glsl, shader

I'm trying to pass in a vector to an already existing three js fragment shader with `onBeforeCompile` like this:

```
var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
            map: myLoadedTexture,
            shininess: 0,
            bumpMap: myBumpMap,
            bumpScale: 0.1,
            fog: true
        });

let myVector = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0);

material.userData.myVector = { value: myVector };

material.onBeforeCompile = function (shader) {

     shader.uniforms.myVector = material.userData.myVector;

     shader.fragmentShader = 'uniform vec3 myVector;\n' + shader.fragmentShader;
     shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace('#include <map_fragment>',
     `
     // some other code here

     // If I comment this out, the shader runs
     float result = dot(vNormal, myVector);


     `)
}
```

I get the following error: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'needsUpdate' of undefined` which looks very strange since the vector is defined.

Any hints ?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace(...)`? And what is `'stringToReplace'` in the shader?

Comment: @prisoner849 it's just an example for a snippet inside the fragment shader that I can replace.

Comment: When and where do you try to set `.needsUpdate`? Could you provide a working live code example? (code snippet, jsfiddle, codepen)

Comment: @prisoner849 I do not set it, do I have to set it? I used onBeforeCompile to put other things into the fragment shader, but I never had to set it ...

Comment: It's hard to help, having just abstract code. Maybe it's better to ask this question on the [forum](https://discourse.threejs.org/)

Answer (score 0):

You code works for me. I think your error is somewhere else.

```js
function main() {
  const canvas = document.querySelector('#c');
  const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({canvas});

  const fov = 75;
  const aspect = 2;  // the canvas default
  const near = 0.1;
  const far = 5;
  const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(fov, aspect, near, far);
  camera.position.z = 2;

  const scene = new THREE.Scene();

  {
    const color = 0xFFFFFF;
    const intensity = 1;
    const light = new THREE.DirectionalLight(color, intensity);
    light.position.set(-1, 2, 4);
    scene.add(light);
  }

  const boxWidth = 1;
  const boxHeight = 1;
  const boxDepth = 1;
  const geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(boxWidth, boxHeight, boxDepth);

  const loader = new THREE.TextureLoader();
  const myLoadedTexture = loader.load('https://i.imgur.com/fqgm8uh.png');
  const myBumpMap = myLoadedTexture;

  var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({
              map: myLoadedTexture,
              shininess: 0,
              bumpMap: myBumpMap,
              bumpScale: 0.1,
              fog: true
          });

  let myVector = new THREE.Vector3(1,0,0);

  material.userData.myVector = { value: myVector };

  material.onBeforeCompile = function (shader) {

       shader.uniforms.myVector = material.userData.myVector;

       shader.fragmentShader = 'uniform vec3 myVector;\n' + shader.fragmentShader;
       shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace('#include <map_fragment>',
       `
       // some other code here

       // If I comment this out, the shader runs
       float result = dot(vNormal, myVector);


       `)
  }  

  const cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
  scene.add(cube);

  function render(time) {
    time *= 0.001;  // convert time to seconds

    cube.rotation.x = time;
    cube.rotation.y = time;

    renderer.render(scene, camera);

    requestAnimationFrame(render);
  }
  requestAnimationFrame(render);

}

main();
```

```html
<canvas id="c"></canvas>
<script src="https://threejsfundamentals.org/threejs/resources/threejs/r108/build/three.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I copied it wrong, it actually already is ` shader.fragmentShader = shader.fragmentShader.replace ` and what I then replace is `#include <map_fragment>`, I'll edit my question

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code you posted. Please use a [snippet](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/) next time with a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: I actually found out where the error was. I loaded a texture with an async loader into the uniforms, it worked (even if it shouldnt have) until I put the vector too into the uniforms. The texture was not loaded as onBeforeCompile executed. Do not know why it came out later, but that was definitely the cause.